# Display Image from folder in Picturebox (one by one)

Tags: vb.net, image, vb6, picturebox

I wanna ask something. this piece of code loads an image from a `dir` to `picturebox` right?

`Picturebox1.Image = LoadPicture("path")`

Now here is my question lets say I have 30 picturebox in a form and a random number of image in a folder.

My question is how can I load those images one by one? Insert it there. For example I have 5 Image in a  folder then those 5 will load and the number of image is random (means min 1 and max 30)

TYSM for help

Comment: timer and random number

Comment: what do u mean timer and random number?

Comment: i want to know about the timer but the random number, No, I think you dony understand the random number that means the random number is the quantity or the count of how many images inside of the folder.

Comment: I think, I perfectly understand what you need and I just gave you the path to success. You need timer to trigger the image change periodically. And you need a random number to randomly select next image from the **arbitrary** list. Unless you want images to change in same order, then you need a *"resetting index"*. However, all above said, your question falls under category *"This question does not show any research effort"*. A code like this can be found on google.

Comment: Well atleast that one enlighten me, TY so much for help